# Am getting the table data as array of strings, how to convert them to array of jsons

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the data am getting

```
["node_name", "ip", "name", "active", "0YXe_ws", "10.0.10.147", "generic", "0", ]
```

First four elements are column names and next four elements are values of those column names. I want the data as

```
[
  {
    "node_name": "0YXe_ws",
    "ip":"10.0.10.147", 
    "name":"generic", 
    "active":"0"
  }
]
```

I have tried by dividing the array by four elements and it didnt work

Comment: Stack-over flow is not a free coding service you need to provide us your minimum efforts to achieve this or if you are stuck at something ? Please do your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a minimal example of your work. Read here how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

If you can make sure your mentioned strucutre is always the same, a simple for loop should do the trick.

Simply divide the array length to run over all keys and add the half length of the array to each key to get the corresponding value.

```js
let arr = ["node_name", "ip", "name", "active", "0YXe_ws", "10.0.10.147", "generic", "0"];
let data = {}
for(let i=0;i<arr.length / 2;i++){
  data[arr[i]] = arr[i+arr.length/2];
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chunk your data into arrays containing by firstly creating a `chunk` function. You can then make a `zip` function which you can use to merge each arrays data together. Once you've done that, you can chunk your data into fours again and map over each entry with `Object.fromEntries()` to obtain your objects:

```js
const arr = ["node_name", "ip", "name", "active", "0YXe_ws", "10.0.10.147", "generic", "0"];

const chunk = (arr, s) =>
  arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, s), ...chunk(arr.slice(s), 4)] : [];  
const zip = arrs => arrs[0].map((_, i) => arrs.map(arr => arr[i]));

const res = chunk(chunk(arr, 4), 2).map(arr => Object.fromEntries(zip(arr)))
console.log(res);
```

Example of flow:

```
["node_name", "ip", "name", "active", "0YXe_ws", "10.0.10.147", "generic", "0", ];
```

Apply `chunk(arr, 4)` on above data your data chunked into elements of four:

```
[
  ["node_name","ip","name","active"],
  ["0YXe_ws","10.0.10.147","generic","0"]
]
```

Apply `chunk(arr, 2)` to the above array. This will group keys and entries for each object into its own array:

```
[
  [
    ["node_name","ip","name","active"],
    ["0YXe_ws","10.0.10.147","generic","0"]
  ]
]
```

This is then iterated on using `.map()`. Each inner array zipped first to create an array of `[key, value]` pair entries. An example of the above inner array if converted into (note this is still wrapped by the outer array):

```
[
  ["node_name","0YXe_ws"],
  ["ip","10.0.10.147"],
  ["name","generic"],
  ["active","0"]
]
```

As this array now takes the correct form of `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2, ...]` we can use `Object.fromEntries()` on it, which takes an array of this form and converts it into an object for us. So, the above gets transformed into the following object. Resulting in the final result of:

```
[
  {
    node_name: "0YXe_ws", 
    ip: "10.0.10.147", 
    name: "generic", 
    active: "0"
   }
]
```

As a result, this method will work if you have an array with multiple keys and multiple objects, creating multiple objects like so:

```js
const arr = ["node_name", "ip", "name", "active", "0YXe_ws", "10.0.10.147", "generic", "0", "node_name", "ip", "name", "active", "1ABf_xy", "127.0.0.1", "abc", "1"];

const chunk = (arr, s) =>
  arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, s), ...chunk(arr.slice(s), 4)] : [];  
const zip = arrs => arrs[0].map((_, i) => arrs.map(arr => arr[i]));

const res = chunk(chunk(arr, 4), 2).map(arr => Object.fromEntries(zip(arr)))
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could separate keys and values and reduce the values array by looking to the index and the corresponding key.

```js
var data = ["node_name", "ip", "name", "active", "0YXe_ws", "10.0.10.147", "generic", "0", "sms", "10.0.10.17", "normal", "1"],
    length = 4,
    keys = data.slice(0, length),
    result = data.slice(length).reduce((r, v, i) => {
        const index = Math.floor(i / length);
        r[index] = r[index] || {};
        r[index][keys[i % length]] = v;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```